# How do I install libcap on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: c, linux, networking, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to get libcap to work on my machine (running Ubuntu 12.04) but I am currently unable to get this done:

Here is how it all began:

1. In Eclipse I got the warning that it could not resolve `pcap.h`.
   It said `Unresolved inclusion <pcap.h>`
2. I installed libcap like this: `sudo apt-get install libcap-dev`
3. I restarted my machine.

And now I am still getting the warning that it cannot resolve `pcap.h`.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone.. this is really frustrating..

Comment: I think you may need to install the _`libpcap`_ library, not the `libcap` library, e.g.: `apt-get install libpcap-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing linux-headers, but you will need to know your kernel version:

Ex.:

```
tiago@dell:~$ sudo uname -a
Linux dell 3.11.0-20-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:32:55 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

tiago@dell:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.11.0-20
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.11.0-20 is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```